# Can't access current_user inside .new do block in the ApplicationController

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise and the bitbucket api gem and I have a method in my ApplicationController which creates an instance so I can make API calls. To do that, it tries to read the token and secret from the current_user.

This works fine with hardcoded token and secret strings, I'm also able to do `puts current_user.inspect` before the do block, and that all works fine. I'm also sure that bb_token and bb_secret exist (I'm able to call puts on them individually).

But once I try to create my bitbucket instance, it can't read current_user anymore. Any ideas?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user

  def bitbucket

    puts "token----------"
    puts current_user

    @bitbucket = BitBucket.new do |config|
      config.oauth_token   = current_user.bb_token # replaceing this with hardcoded string works
      config.oauth_secret  = current_user.bb_secret # replaceing this with hardcoded string works
      config.client_id     = 'xx'
      config.client_secret = 'yy'
      config.adapter       = :net_http
    end
  end

end
```

And the error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<BitBucket::Client:0x007fbebc92f540>):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:12:in `block in bitbucket'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:11:in `bitbucket'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems block passed to `BitBucket.new` is executed in context of new `BitBucket::Client` instance (`BitBucket.new` is really `BitBucket::Client.new`, according to [this](https://github.com/vongrippen/bitbucket/blob/master/lib/bitbucket_rest_api.rb#L23)).

A glance to the [source](https://github.com/vongrippen/bitbucket/blob/master/lib/bitbucket_rest_api/api.rb#L44) confirms this supposition.

If you want to pass `current_user`, you can recall that the blocks are closures, so they keep the context in which they are defined. So you can do something like this:

```
def bitbucket
  # (...)
  user = current_user # local variable assignment
  @bitbucket = BitBucket.new do |config|
    config.oauth_token = user.bb_token # it works because user is local variable and the block is closure
    # (...)
  end
end
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it's not working. Still showing the same error.

Comment: `user = current_user` lines hold the return value of the method.. Using that,you are calling the method inside a block. Am I right?

Comment: @ArupRakshit no, using that, you call method before block and assign local variable to its result. Then, you simply use this local variable in block, as you usually do in closures.

Comment: @MarekLipka I understand that.. What you are saying I already comment..means I understand it correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Inside `BitBucket.new` `do..end` block,`self` is set to `config`. But `current_user` is not a instance method of `BitBucket` class. Thus a valid error is thrown.